# ArcGis Layers Not Loading on Xamarin.iOS App - Invalid JSON Exception

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-runtime

Am currently using the Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.iOS v100.0.0 version on the following version of Xamarin Studio for Mac(6.1.2 build 44) with Xamarin.IOS Version: 10.2.1.5 & XCode Version 8.1.

I get the following Exception when attempting to load a Feature Layer by doing a LoadAsync on the ServiceFeatureTable queried from a given URL. **“Esri.ArcGISRuntimeException: Invalid JSON at System RuntimeExceptionServices.Exception”** following is the code used.

```
// create a service feature table of census block groups
var blockGroupsUri = new Uri(Config.MapServerUrl + "/" + layer.ID);
var featureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable(blockGroupsUri);
featureTable.FeatureRequestMode =   
FeatureRequestMode.OnInteractionCache;

// load the feature table
await featureTable.LoadAsync();
featureTables.Add(featureTable);
var lyr = new FeatureLayer(featureTable);
myMap.OperationalLayers.Add(lyr);
```

This only happens for certain layers, have tried validating the JSON returned from querying the layer, there seems to be no issue there. The attributes on the Layers that work and don’t work are pretty much the same.

But the thing to note here is that, the above layer in question loads up on the map fine when its saved in a GeoDatabase (for offline querying), and when queried using the GeodatabaseFeatureTable subsequently.